# Nulls In JComboBox Stopping Arrow Key Use

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

The code below has a bug. Upon loading the JFrame, press tab to focus on the JComboBox, and try pressing the down key. It doesn't do anything.

Inserting Null at position 0 causes this. However, I would still like to be able to select Null. I don't want to force the user to pick an option.

```
package kobalt.test.colin;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ColinTest extends JFrame {

    private JTextField mTextField;
    private JComboBox  mComboBox;

    public ColinTest(){
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      mTextField = new JTextField("Something");
      mComboBox = new JComboBox(new String[]{"One", "Two"});
      mComboBox.insertItemAt(null, 0); //this line causes the bug

      add(mTextField, "North");
      add(mComboBox, "South");

      pack();
      setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] argv) {
      new ColinTest();
    }
}
```

Is there something I can override in JComboBox to fix this behaviour?

I don't really fancy inserting an empty String at position 0 as I'll have to deal with that everywhere.

Using a Wrapping object may be an option, but I'd rather extend and then override something in JComboBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Null objects do not play nicely in a JComboBox. For example, the combo box's `getSelectedIndex` method, which is fired when you select an item, will return -1 if the object is `null`. There may also be other methods which perform null checks and may return incorrect results.

But you can try overriding the `getSelectedIndex` so that it returns 0 instead of -1 if the object is null. Also override `selectedItemChanged`  so that it doesn't check for nulls. The following seems to work, but there may be other methods which need to be overridden too:

```
JComboBox mComboBox = new JComboBox(new String[]{"One", "Two"}){
    @Override
    public int getSelectedIndex() {
        Object sObject = dataModel.getSelectedItem();
        int i,c;
        Object obj;

        if(sObject==null){
            return 0;
        }
        for ( i=0,c=dataModel.getSize();i<c;i++ ) {
            obj = dataModel.getElementAt(i);

             if ( obj != null && obj.equals(sObject) )
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void selectedItemChanged() {
        fireItemStateChanged(new ItemEvent(this, ItemEvent.ITEM_STATE_CHANGED,
                selectedItemReminder,
                ItemEvent.DESELECTED));
        selectedItemReminder = dataModel.getSelectedItem();

        fireItemStateChanged(new ItemEvent(this, ItemEvent.ITEM_STATE_CHANGED,
                selectedItemReminder,
                ItemEvent.SELECTED));
    }
};
```

**However, instead of doing the above, I would recommend using a wrapper object**. For example:

```
class StringWrapper{
    final String s;
    public StringWrapper(String s){
        this.s=s;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return s;
    }
}

JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(new StringWrapper[]{ 
            new StringWrapper("one"),
            new StringWrapper("two"),
            new StringWrapper("three")});
cb.insertItemAt(new StringWrapper(null), 0);
```

Comment: I went with a wrapper object, thanks. I wasn't a fan of the sentence "there may be other methods which need to be overridden too" :)

Answer (score 1):

Creation of combobox in such a way creates DefaultComboBoxModel which is based on Vector. So nulls can't be inserted. You can try to implement your ComboBoxModel with nulls support.

Comment: -1 This is wrong. Nulls can be inserted into the model. It is the combobox which behaves differently if the element is null.